# conditional content

Tags: conditionals

I'm writing a document in LaTeX that I want to compile in two different versions, V1 and V2 (with two different formatting specifications). Sometimes I need to insert a bit of content into V1 that isn't in V2, and vice versa. To specify which version is being compiled, I have a variable called `cond`, which I set to `True` to flag the V1 formatting, and `False` to flag the V2 formatting. Then, the following commands are specified:

```
% Display the argument if \cond is True
\newcommand{\IfCondTrue}[1]{\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\cond}{True}{#1}{}}

% Display the argument if \cond is False
\newcommand{\IfCondFalse}[1]{\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\cond}{True}{}{#1}}
```

Thus, to insert content into V1 that isn't in V2, I simply insert it into the command `\IfCondTrue{...}`.

This works exactly as desired except for one issue; when the content that I'm inserting is paragraph text, eg. `This is fake \IfCondTrue{text}.`. If `cond` is set to `False`, then the word `text` won't display, as desired. Unfortunately, it *will* be replaced with an empty space. For example, suppose in V1 I want to have `This is fake text.` and in V2 I want to have `This is fake hooplah.`, then ideally I could write: `This is fake \IfCondTrue{text}\IfCondFalse{hooplah}.`. Then, when V1 compiles, what I'll see is `This is fake text .` (with a space between `text` and `.`.

How can I modify the above commands so that they won't display an empty space when their content is not displayed?

Thanks

Comment: Note that the space isn't generated _by the commands_ it is the space in your document text _between_ the commands, so the simplest is not to add that space.

Comment: You can end the definitions with `\ignorespaces` then use `\ ` if you need a space.

Comment: I haven't put any space between the two commands in that sample text block. I've just settled on the following hack:

`This is fake\IfCondTrue{ text.}\IfCondTrue{hooplah. }`

In this way, the commands automatically account for the spaces introduced by the other commands. Note particularly elegant but it's a bit convenient.

Comment: There is a space (linebreak) between the `\IfCondTrue{text}` and `\IfCondFalse{hooplah}` in the example above, do you mean that isn't in your real code? (This is why it is always best to post a complete document so the problem can be reproduced)

Comment: I don't know if I'm being thick, but I don't know what you're talking about. I don't believe I inserted a line break, nor do I see one in what I posted.

Comment: sorry I see a break in the rendered view but if I look at the edit view of what you actually posted there is no break. Ignore my comments:-) (It's better to post your code using the `{}` button rather than `backticks` as then it is set as a pre and no spurious spaces are inserted, but I should have checked the source:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could `\unskip` and/or `\ignorespaces` as part of your condition. However, version control is easier when you combine the possible outputs in a single macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% Display the argument if \cond is True/False
\newcommand{\IfCond}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\cond}{True}=0
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{}{#1}=0\unskip\else#1\fi%
  \else
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{}{#2}=0\unskip\else#2\fi%
  \fi\ignorespaces}

% Display the argument if \cond is False
\newcommand{\IfCondFalse}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\cond}{True}=0 \unskip\else #1\fi\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\def\cond{True}% Version control
This is fake \IfCond{text}{hooplah}. \par
This is fake \IfCond{}{hooplah}.

\def\cond{False}% Version control
This is fake \IfCond{text}{hooplah}. \par
This is fake \IfCond{text}{}.
\end{document}
```

String comparison is done using pdfTeX's `\pdfstrcmp`.