# Add text which can be turned on or off during compilation

Tags: macros, conditionals

I have written a book in LaTeX which I am reviewing at the moment. However, in the book, I want to insert more details for e.g. a printed version. Thus, I am searching for a possible option to include text that is compiled and shown in the document based on a variable (such as a debug flag). I want to give an example. The first version should have the following text:

```
The keywords has to be added to the \textit{fvSolution} file, 
otherwise, the solver might indicate an error.
```

For the second version I would like to extend the text:

```
The keywords has to be added to the \textit{fvSolution} file, 
otherwise, the solver might indicate an error. \secondVersion{However, default
values are used if nothing is specified}
```

I also might use it for coloring text in the second version such as:

```
The \secondVersion{\{\red}keywords\secondVersion{\}} has to be 
added to the \textit{fvSolution} file, otherwise, the solver might
indicate an error.
```

During compiling the text inside `\secondVersion{}` should be compiled if a flag is set or not. I guess something like that might be possible. Any hints are appreaciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461973/134574, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33576/134574, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131726/134574, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5894/134574, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308101/134574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define two commands:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifsecondversion

% text that should be omitted in the first version
\newcommand{\sv}[1]{%
  \ifsecondversion
    #1%
  \else
    \@bsphack\expandafter\@esphack
  \fi
}
% text that should be colored in the second version
\newcommand{\svx}[2][red]{%
  \ifsecondversion
    \textcolor{#1}{#2}%
  \else
    #2%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\secondversionfalse

The \svx{keywords} has to be added to the \textit{fvSolution} file, 
otherwise, the solver might indicate an error. \sv{However, default
values are used if nothing is specified.} Blah, \svx[blue]{blah}.

\secondversiontrue

The \svx{keywords} has to be added to the \textit{fvSolution} file, 
otherwise, the solver might indicate an error. \sv{However, default
values are used if nothing is specified.} Blah, \svx[blue]{blah}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a much nicer way than I added yesterday. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Just one question, if one uses, e.g., `begin{lstlisting}` inside the `\sv{}` it is not working. There is a message: `! Extra \else.`

Comment: @Tobi You can't have verbatim environments (including `lstlisting`) in the argument to another command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Phelype Oleinik for the hints in the comment section. I used the following approach https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33579/116084 which lead to:

```
\newif\ifsecondVersion
\secondVersiontrue

\begin{document}
The \ifsecondVersion {\red \fi keywords \ifsecondVersion }\fi has to be 
added to the \textit{fvSolution} file, otherwise, the solver might
indicate an error.
\end{document}
```

Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
...
\newcommand{\secondVersion}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\secondVersion}[1]{}
...
```

and comment out the version you don't want?

Comment: You need to do something about spaces surrounding `\secondVersion`'s argument in case of not printing the text. Therefore - as also proposed by egreg: `\newcommand{\secondVersion}[1]{#1}`
`\newcommand{\secondVersion}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}`